# Software for creating interactive dashboard in Python

Tags: python, gui, user-interface, dashboard

I need to create an interactive dashboard where users can choose values from dropdown lists/ check boxes... etc and charts change based on the values users choose.

I want the interface to be user friendly so that people with no knowledge of Python can use it.

Data will be imported from SQL Server and used to create the charts.

I have only used Jupyter Notebooks, and I need to use some other software.

Comment: Desktop or web interface?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I just need to share it with people in my company.

Comment: Can you give suggestions for both?

Comment: Not personally, but I’m interested in the answers you do get.